# How do I save an SVG file to see it in browsers?

Tags: browser, safari, svg

I can't understand how to save an SVG image for using it in broswes.
I can see [this](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/retina/img/apple.svg), but can't see [this](http://i.puush.ru/images/logo.svg).
I need your help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The svg is malformed in your second example.  Pulling it up in Inkscape shows that you've got some problems with mis-matched quotes.  It looks like your Illustrator is having some issues with export for you.  Does this render correctly in Illustrator?